# What are the IP adresses of the clash royale servers?

Tags: clash-royale

What is/are the IPs and their ports of the Clash Royale servers or how can I find them myself? I would like to block the access to this game on different devices (iOS and Android).

Comment: Why do you want that?

Comment: @DeMize I imagine to block others from playing the game e.g. children. Or to prevent addiction of him/her self of the game?

Comment: yes that's the main reason...in truth what we would like to do at school it is to be able to "control" or choose when the children can play and when not.  I'm wondering if it's possible to do it thorough our router....As we usually do with the website....

Comment: In this case I would ask SuperCell developers if they can help you  because if you want to stop kids from playing in school, you can ask developers if they would be that nice and block your route to their servers... I doubt they will tell you their servers IP and ports.

Comment: You can always delete the game and remove the App Store, I presume the data of the Clash Royale game would be still in the phone.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  It is asking for an IP to block particular network traffic. As we could replace the game with alter ate software (say, an unwanted software updater), and still have the same question/problem, this question is not within the scope of Arqade.

Comment: This is specific to the game.  HOW to block an IP is off-topic.  How to block specific game server IPs seems to be rather well in-scope.  As always, the tech support acid test is: Take the problem, and remove the game.  Does the problem still exist?  If yes, then it's a good bet it's not on-topic.  This question does not fail the acid test.

Answer (score 1):

Everything goes through game.clashroyaleapp.com

Answer (score 1):

54.201.164.141 port:9339 -> 56927. for u.s server. I don't know why you need it but whatever. Dont try to ddos it it won't do anything

Comment: And you can find it easy get interceptor ng for your phone skip scan make sure your connected to clash royales server then APR SCAN the shark the ips then look for com.clashroyale or something like that. Or another way look for your phone ip make sure clash royal is the only server your connected to and then look for your phone ip then next to its should be the server ip and then click on the ip and it will give you the port.